# Command in variable does not update

Tags: shell, unix, sh

What is the right way to assign commands into variable; a.k.a how should I use quote commas and how assign it to variable, so the command is up to date? For example

I am at `home/desktop`.
I assign variable

```
b=`pwd`
echo "$b" // home/desktop
```

but when I change the directory

```
cd games
pwd // home/desktop/games
echo "$b" // home/desktop
```

it does not update. Also  I want to do something like

```
g="-l"
ls $g
```

is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need a variable at all in your first case? Just use `pwd` in backticks.

Comment: i want to know it in order to learn something more. And propably i will need this for school , not sure tho

Comment: Then you can't do that. The point of using a variable is that its value doesn't magically change behind your back.

Answer (score 1):

Variables never update automatically, you have to re-assign them, i.e.,

```
b=`pwd`
echo "$b" // home/desktop 
cd games
pwd // home/desktop/games
b=`pwd`
echo "$b" // home/desktop/games
```

as for your second question, I think that's only possible using `eval`:

```
g=" -la"
eval "ls"$g
```

**BE VERY CAREFUL WITH THIS** It's very easy to write something that can compromise security and indeed most people (including myself!) would strongly advise you never to use `eval` unless all else has failed.
Consider the code above for demonstration purposes only, under no circumstances to be used in a production system.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is only set when you run the first command (assigning the output of `pwd` to `b`, it doesn't link those items together (so that b gets set on every invocation). There are ways to do that also (do `man bash` on your machine)  (for example, the shell variable `$PWD` contains this information.

to your second question, yes, you can do that, but a nice way to so it is to use `alias`.  So, `alias ll='ls -l'` creates a command on your system that will run `ls -l` when you type `ll`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing assigning variables with aliases.
assigning a variable means you store the result of the command in a variable
what this command does

```
b=`pwd`
```

is running `pwd` and stores the answer in a variable b.

and alias means giving some command a different name. so running `alias b pwd` will make it so whenever you run b, you will actually run `pwd`